# iPad: Specific/exact position of items for different resolutions

Tags: ios, ipad, resolution, ios-autolayout

I would like to position UI elements at specific positions on an image, for all iPad resolutions.
Imagine a ground plan with different icons/buttons on top. Each icon should be at a very specific position (e.g. exactly in the kitchen, floor, ...). When changing the device/resolution (iPad only) the icons should stay at the correct position, according to the background/ground plan imageView.

See the images (only quick examples): The smallest iPad (9.7") would be the correct position. The other image (12.9") shows the wrong position. (For all iPad sizes, I only chose two examples)

9.7": [image]
12.9": [image]

I can't get a way or idea to achieve this positioning problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making your "bulb" positions relative to the size of the "floor plan" image view.

For example:

- suppose your floor plan image is `1800 x 1500` and your bulb images are `96 x 96` (I'm estimating, based on the images you posted)...
- and let's say the center of the top-left bulb is at `276, 486`
- and the imageView holding your floor plan is `900 x 750` (half the original size)

You would set:

```
xScale = 900 / 1800 (0.5)
yScale = 750 / 1500 (0.5)

bulb width = 96 * xScale
bulb height = 96 * yScale

bulb center = 276 * xScale, 486 * yScale
```

Here is some sample code that may help you get started:

```
class FloorPlanViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var floorPlanView: UIImageView!

    var bulbs: [UIImageView] = [UIImageView]()

    var centers: [CGPoint] = [
        CGPoint(x: 276, y: 486),
        CGPoint(x: 276, y: 648),
        CGPoint(x: 640, y: 486),
        CGPoint(x: 640, y: 648),
        CGPoint(x: 877, y: 486),
        CGPoint(x: 877, y: 648),
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in centers {
            let v = bulbImageView()
            floorPlanView.addSubview(v)
            bulbs.append(v)
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if let fpImage = floorPlanView.image {

            let xScale = floorPlanView.frame.width / fpImage.size.width
            let yScale = floorPlanView.frame.height / fpImage.size.height

            for i in 0..<centers.count {

                let thisCenter = centers[i]
                let thisBulb = bulbs[i]

                thisBulb.frame.size.width = 96.0 * xScale
                thisBulb.frame.size.height = 96.0 * yScale

                thisBulb.center = CGPoint(x: thisCenter.x * xScale, y: thisCenter.y * yScale)

            }
        }

    }

    func bulbImageView() -> UIImageView {
        let v = UIImageView()
        if let img = UIImage(named: "bulb96x96") {
            v.image = img
        } else {
            v.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        return v
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be difficult because in the screenshots you added, the images look to be fitted to the screen size, meaning their content is transformed to fit within the frame. In that case, you will have have to calculate a transform ratio between the actual image size and the frame size and update your child view's positions to the new ratio.

One alternative is to embed the image view inside of a scrollview and have it match the image's full-size height and width. In this case, you would always have a 1:1 aspect ratio, and not have to reposition the child views. However, you would have to scroll within the scrollview to view the image.